# Hallar el rumbo u orientación magnética de un teléfono móvil con Javascript

Tags: javascript, api

Me gustaría obtener el rumbo magnético (u orientación magnética) de una fotografía tomada con la cámara trasera de un teléfono móvil.
Hasta el momento he podido acceder, de forma individual, a los datos de los siguientes sensores: giróscopo, acelerómetro y magnetómetro, pero cuando trato de acceder a todos a la vez solo me permite acceder a uno de ellos.
Por ello me pregunto si existe alguna API, dll o similar de JS o alguna página web que explique y muestre código sobre cómo capturar la información y utilizarla para obtener el rumbo.
Muchas gracias.
Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Javascript cuenta con una herramienta para detectar la orientacion de un dispositivo aunque no estoy muy seguro si esto te ayudara a lograr lo que quieres con tu programa, aqui esta la documentacion: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Device_orientation_events/Detecting_device_orientation

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Lo voy a investigar. Saludos.